# Is it possible to use a JSP custom tag within a velocity template?

Tags: java, jsp, velocity, jsp-tags, freemarker

I have a custom tag library that I want to use from within my velocity templates. Is it possible to do so?

I want the facility to be somewhat similar to what is provided with free marker.

Answer (score 2):

Not trivially.

If you can find the old VeloTags project you might be able to hack something together, but IMO it's almost certainly not worth it.

Are the custom tags *that* difficult to abstract and turn into a Velocity Tool? Is there a technical reason why using FreeMarker isn't feasible?

Comment: Maybe not a big deal however consolidating technology usage is one of my objectives. In our company we use JSP's, Free Marker and Velocity. I want to see if we can focus on one or maybe two technologies if possible.

Comment: FreeMarker is the most versatile, since you *can* embed JSP tag libraries in the web layer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Freemarker?  Assuming you really can't, the VelocityViewTag in VelocityTools 2.0 makes it easy to embed Velocity within JSP, which certainly works a lot better than past attempts i've seen at embedding JSP inside Velocity.

Comment: Definitely easier to embed V in JSP than vice-versa!

Comment: Using FreeMarker is certainly a choice. Using JSP's is also a choice I just wanted to get some good pros and cons lined up for all three technologies.